# Atualizar o Angular cli dentro de projeto

Tags: angular

Boa tarde pessoal.
Estou tentando atualizar o Angular cli em um projeto.
1. Atualizei o Angular globalmente "npm install -g @angular/cli" atualizou para o Angular 6.0.8.
2. Tentei atualizar o angular do projeto. Na raiz do projeto deu o seguinte comando:
"npm install @angular/cli", e deu o seguinte erro.

npm WARN The package angular2-jwt is included as both a dev and production dependency.

npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\didam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-06-27T19_18_55_325Z-debug.log
PS D:\2018\ALGAWORKS\Spring Boot + Angular\didamendes-algamoney-ui> npm install -g @angular/cli
C:\Users\didam\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\didam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng

> @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall C:\Users\didam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
>   node ./bin/ng-update-message.js

Comment: como esta seu package.json?

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda ajuda Eduardo Vargas. Conseguir atualizar ! Apaguei o node modules e mandei de novo o npm install, ai depois depois o update do angular e do ng update funcionou !!!